# gstreamer using GstVideoOverlay crashes the program

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am currently trying to make a video appear inside a GLFWwindow. But whenever i try to use my pre-defined GstVideoOverlay inside my `bus_sync_handler` function, it crashes my program. Here's the code that crashes:

```
GstBusSyncReply gVideo::bus_sync_handler(GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, Data *data) {

    g_print("overlay 1\n");

    if(!data->overlay) {
        g_print("NULL");
    }
    .
    .
```

The program just crashes in here. Data is my pre-defined struct which goes as:

```
struct VideoData {
    GstElement *convert;
    GstElement *sink;
    GstCaps *caps;
};

struct AudioData {
    GstElement *convert;
    GstElement *resample;
    GstElement *sink;
};

struct Data {
    AudioData a_data;
    VideoData v_data;
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source;
    GstVideoOverlay *overlay;
} data;
```

And here's where i send my data to my vbus handler:

```
bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);

logi("bus 1");

gst_bus_set_sync_handler(bus, (GstBusSyncHandler)bus_sync_handler, NULL, NULL);

logi("bus 2");
```

And here's the list of errors I am getting:

```
...
#10   Object "", at 0x6dc52acb, in gst_memory_new_wrapped
#9    Object "", at 0x6dc76770, in gst_element_get_type
#8    Object "", at 0x6dc621e9, in gst_bus_post
#7    Object "", at 0x6dc50528, in gst_memory_new_wrapped
#6    Object "", at 0x6dca56f1, in gst_param_spec_array
#5    Object "", at 0x6dc52e1f, in gst_memory_new_wrapped
#4    Object "", at 0x6dc79dd7, in gst_element_post_message
#3    Object "", at 0x6dc52acb, in gst_memory_new_wrapped
#2    Object "", at 0x6dc76770, in gst_element_get_type
#1    Object "", at 0x6dc621e9, in gst_bus_post
#0    Object "", at 0x6192b566, in ZN6gVideo16bus_sync_handlerEP7_GstBusP11_GstMessagePNS_4DataE
```

And they just keep going on. I just don't get why the GstVideoOverlay is crashing my program. Do I have to initialize it with a certain value? If so, I am initializing it with NULL inside my constructor, but nothing changes. Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Apparently `data` is NULL in that callback - is `data` perhaps one of those NULLs that you pass to `gst_bus_set_sync_handler()`? (just guessing here, as you can tell)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Omg, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much, that's such a simple and stupid mistake on my part.